# Invoke marshalled COM interface multiple times

Tags: javascript, com, event-handling, dom-events, activex

I am writing a COM object for JavaScript consumption. JavaScript code is turn runs in an hosted WebBrowserControl. I need to fire some events from COM object to JavaScript, the excellent guide to which  at [Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/invoking-javascript-callbacks-using-com/184416311?pgno=1)

e.g.
I have following in my *.idl

```
IJSCallback
{
    void Listen(IDispatch* pJSMethod);
}
```

JavaScript methods are received as `IDispatch*` in C++ code, which is to be stored for calling it later, from another thread.
No matter what method for marshaling is used (`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` or `IGlobalInterfaceTable`) the event firing thread is able to call JavaScript function only once. After that `IDispatch::Invoke()` returns `E_ACCESSDENIED`!

sample JavaScript code

```
var server = new ActiveXObject("prog_id")
var.Listen(function(ip_add) {
    // ip_add from COM object
});
```

the C++ thread is pretty straight forward.

```
// called from JavaScript
CMyObject::Listen(IDispatch* pJSMethod)
{
    // IStream* m_pStream;
    CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pJSMethod, IID_IDispatch, &m_pStream);
}

// called from internal C++ thread.
CMyObject::FireEvent()
{
    // IStream* m_pStream;
    // IDispatch* m_pJSMethod;
    CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(m_pStream, IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&m_pJSMethod);

    HSREULT hr = m_pJSMethod->Invoke(...); // hr = S_OK, call is received in JavaScript
    hr = m_pJSMethod->Invoke(...); // hr = E_ACCESSDENIED, call is not received in JavaScript
}
```

is this expected behavior? or something wrong in code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oh! I was still editing :)

Comment: Well, there's `AndReleaseStream` part right there in the function name. Quite obviously, you can't call `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` twice on the same stream. Unmarshal once, then cache the resulting pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I understood it hard way, adding to you argument one cannot unmarshall twice even if using `CoUnmarshalInterface`

Comment: One can, but one must a) use `MSHLFLAGS_TABLESTRONG` flag with `CoMarshalInterface`, and b) rewind the stream after each unmarshal (`CoUnmarshalInterface` leaves it positioned at the end).

Comment: thank for clarification, since then I have moved on to using `GlobalInterfaceTable`, but same error.

Comment: Calling `Invoke` twice on unmarshalled pointer is valid (and [works](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/JsFunctionDispatch/Foo.h#L17)), your problem is likely to be elsewhere. For example, the JS callback itself throws Access Denied. Or your code is not as simple as you provided.

Comment: @RomanR. you are right, in JavaScript handler I was calling `document.writeln()`, if I do `alert()` it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. As mentioned in comments `alert()` works but `document.writeln()` doesn't. That is because `document.writeln()` resets the current document including scripts elements, use `document.createElement()`, `document.createTextNode()` and friends to modify current loaded elements.

This could be common knowledge for those familiar with HTML/JavaScript, for rest of us it can be a real deal.